# Is using dotenv necessary if environment variables already declared with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables, dotenv

If I have declared a port variable or anything in the **Dockerfile** of a nodejs project as `ENV PORT=8080`. Is it still necessary or maybe best practice to use the **dotenv** package to load the environment variables as `require('dotenv').config()`?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Node.js applications relies heavily on environment variables.
It is a common thing to load these variables from a `.env` file with your mentioned library, however this is only a good practice and not a strict rule.